# How do I change the subject of my php error email?

Tags: php, error-handling

I have the following:

```
      error_log("big error!!", 1, my email address);
```

When the message is delivered it says "PHP error_log message" in the subject line.

Can someone show me how to customize the message subject?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
error_log("Error message", 1, "me@example.com", "Subject: My custom subject");
```

The fourth parameter of `error_log` allows you to specify custom headers, of which `Subject` is the subject of the email.

Comment: ahh excellent, I new it was something simple like that, thanks much!

Comment: Just for clarity, what is happening is you're specifying the `Subject:` header twice, since [the subject is hardcoded](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L4697) in PHP's source and you end up [specifying it again](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/mail.c#L346) in PHP's internal `mail()` function.

Comment: Well i must say, this seems like a perfect solution yet I still can't get the proper subject to show up. I can get it to take the "From:" header but "Subect:" is not changing?

Comment: If your typo in the comment is what you have in your code, it needs to be fixed. Otherwise, make sure you're separating headers with `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [niet-the-dark-absol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/niet-the-dark-absol)!

I was able to generate this off of your recommendations on separating the headers.

```
<?php

    $dateTime=date("Y_m_d_H_i_s");
    $headers = "From: SOME ROBOT <somerobotyouusedtoknow@somecompany.com>\r\n" .
               "Reply-to: SOME HUMAN <somehumanyoudoknow@somecompany.com>";
               "Subject: My custom subject on including date of: " . $dateTime . "\r\n" .
    $emailto = "JayRizzo@somecompany.com";
    $emailbody = "This is the body of the email: Error message";

error_log($emailbody, 1, $emailto, $headers);

?>
```

I got a proper response and was able to change more than just the Subject or Reply-to or From address.

I'm posting this only because all I find is that you cannot change more than one header at a time, and this proves that wrong. (unless it is just an improvement of the PHP version that I'm using)

> NOTE:
> My version of PHP:
>
> ~: php -v
>
> PHP 7.2.0RC6 (cli) (built: Nov 12 2017 08:50:58) ( NTS )
>
> Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
>
> Zend Engine v3.2.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies