# Change php error_log email subject

Tags: php, email, error-log, subject

When using php's `error_log` to send an email the subject always appears as '**PHP error_log message**'. Here is the code being used:

`error_log( $data, 1, 'test@domain.com', "Subject: This is the subject" );`

I have searched and the only question I can find related is:

[How do I change the subject of my php error email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769672/how-do-i-change-the-subject-of-my-php-error-email)

There is a comment in the above post which suggests that the subject is being added twice, and this is also backed up by a comment on the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php#30792)

Despite the above comments there is no indication how to 'fix' the issue.

Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong or what I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to this with `error_log()`.

Just write your own function and call `mail()` from it. `error_log()` with `1` as message type do the same.